# What's the correct way to set up Django translation?

Tags: python, django, translation, django-i18n, django-modeltranslation

I've got an issue with translations not working on Django 1.6. I've added this to my `settings.py`:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('de', ugettext('German')),
)
```

Also added middlewares:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

As well as to my *.py files whenever I'm using a string which shall be l10nd:

```py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

My templates start with:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
```

And inside the template, I used the `trans` placeholder. E.g.

```
<h1>{% trans "Register a tank" %}</h1>
```

I have provided translations in `locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`:

```
msgid "Register a tank"
msgstr "Einen neuen Tank anmelden"
```

My browser is set to request German content first:
[Browser settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roM5Y.png)

What did I miss?

P.S. The project I'm currently fuzzy around is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/frlan/blankspot

Comment: What is actually happening? English is showing? No translations are showing?

Comment: No translation is showing.

Comment: Do you have `USE_I18N = True`?

Comment: Both activated: `USE_I18N = True`
`USE_L10N = True`

Comment: Do you use u18n url patterns?
`urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns

Comment: Not yet -- From my understanding it should work w/o.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add `LOCALE_PATHS` to `settings.py` and set it as below:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

Note that `LOCALE_PATHS` must be a tuple (look at the comma at the end of the path).

Now based on `LOCALE_PATHS`, the `locale` folder should be in the root of your project.

And be sure that you run the commands `django-admin.py makemessages -l de` and `django-admin.py compilemessages` from the root of your project.

```
djPrj
  |
  +---> djPrj
  |
  +---> djApp
  |
  +---> locale
  |
  +---> templates
```

Also rearrange your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to be `LocaleMiddleware` after `SessionMiddleware` and before `CommonMiddleware` as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Restart your service (`python manage.py runserver`) and check again.

---

Just to ensure that your localization is applied to your Django admin page with the default `django.mo` file of Django, do the following test:

First in main `urls.py` of project replace `patterns` with `i18n_patterns`:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # ...
)
```

Now go to the admin page with a `de` prefix, like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/admin/`
And the admin page should be shown in German.

OK, are you able to see the admin page of Django in German?

Also check your view with the `de` prefix too.

---

According to your [project code](https://github.com/frlan/blankspot), some sentences are not in `trans` blocks. Put them as:

```
{% trans "your sentence" %}
```

Also you must use `ugettext_lazy` instead of `ugettext` in your code for views and models (Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4510998/538284) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4164683/538284).)

Replace this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

with:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

And now everything will work.

Comment: @frlan, Are you able to see Admin page of django in de language ? (I update my answer for that)

Comment: Yes, I am able to see.

Comment: It's possible to upload your code project that doesn't work with minimal use case in somewhere?

Comment: Not exactly the project I originally asked for is available via https://github.com/frlan/blankspot/ -- After creating db connection it should work.

Comment: It's work !, I just add `LANGUAGES` and also `LOCALE_PATHS` to `settings.py` as above, and run `django-admin.py compilemessages` cmd, And then go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/`, then it show me `Registering a gascylinder` as title and `Kontaktiere uns` as header of contact page. (My browser is set to request German content first)

Comment: Fields based on form are still not working :( E.g. http://localhost:8000/contact/ should be translated (First name etc.)

Comment: For fields , you must use `ugettext_lazy` instead of ugettext. replace `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _` with `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

Comment: Verified for contact -- still lagging http://localhost:8000/position/add/. Form is created from model `node_registration/model.py` and put in into template `templates/node_registration/position_form.html`

Comment: @frlan, In your code, for views and models use ugettext_lazy instead of ugettext, look at my updated answer, after that for example `First Name` will show as ` Vorname` in add position page. and all works.

Comment: My fault. Missed to update that particular file. Now it seems to work! Yeah. Huge thx

Comment: Quick question, is `i18n_patterns(...)` only required in the root urls.py file, what about urls.py files in sub-apps that get included in the root urlpatterns?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I used en-gb as the parameter to run

`django-admin.py makemessages -l en-gb`

Instead, it should be en_GB.

`django-admin.py makemessages -l en_GB`

Answer (score 2):

Please set `translated string` in `django.po` and then use `python manage.py compilemessages`

```
for e.g 

#: path/to/python/module.py:23
msgid "Welcome to my site."
msgstr "put appropriate translated string here"
```

Suggestion-: You can use `django-rosetta` package to add `translated string` from UI interface. It is easy to add T-string from django-admin. https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta

Comment: I already did this (and updated the question right at the moment -- missed taht. Sry.)

Comment: Did you add django-view for set language and HTML dropdown code for passing lang to that view ?

Comment: Only did what I mentioned above. My thought was Django determins by itself the language. (in borders)

Comment: But django-rosetta looks really nice.

Answer (score 2):

Check the cookies and the session -- according to [How Django Discovers Language Preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), the process is this:

1. language prefix in the URL, when using i18n_patterns in URLconf
2. _language key in the current user's session
3. django_language cookie (or as specified by settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME)
4. Accept-Language HTTP header (this is what your browser setting sends)
5. settings.LANGUAGE_CODE

Since your browser settings are set to prefer 'de', I suspect the LocaleMiddleware must decide otherwise in one of the previous steps 1. - 3.

Answer (score 1):

For example below, you can translate **English** to **French**. *I use Django 4.2.3.

First, create `locale` folder just under `django-project` as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#answer-72359515) explaining how to set templates:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-views.py
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-models.py
 |  |_admin.py
 |  └-apps.py
 |-my_app2
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html  
 └-locale # Here
```

Then, set `core/settings.py` as shown below. *`LocaleMiddleware` must be between `SessionMiddleware` and `CommonMiddleware`. `'en-us'` is set to `LANGUAGE_CODE` by default in `core/settings.py`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', # Here
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = ( # Here
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French'))
)
```

And, `Hello` and `World` are translated with [gettext()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) and outputted on console and `index.html` is rendered in `test()` in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160770/gettext-vs-gettext-lazy-in-django/76510884#76510884) explaining where to use `gettext()` and [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy):

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def test(request):
    print(_("Hello"), _("World")) # Here
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And, `test()` path is set to `urlpatterns` in `my_app1/urls.py` as shown below. *You can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527974/how-to-translate-url-in-django) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527974/how-to-translate-url-in-django/76527975#76527975) explaining how to translate url in Django:

```py
# "my_app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "my_app1"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.test, name="test") # Here
]
```

And, `admin` and `my_app1` paths are set to `urlpatterns` with [i18n_patterns()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns) in `core/urls.py` as shown below. *You can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76310575/how-to-make-the-urls-with-and-without-a-language-prefix-work-in-django-i18n) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76310575/how-to-make-the-urls-with-and-without-a-language-prefix-work-in-django-i18n#answer-76310576) explaining [prefix_default_language=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) with `i18n_patterns()`:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # Here
    path('my_app1/', include('my_app1.urls')) # Here
)
```

And, 3 tags are set in `templates/index.py` as shown below. *For the translation in Django Templates, `{% load i18n %}` is needed and `{% translate %}` or `{% trans %}` can translate:

```
# "templates/index.py"

{% load i18n %}

{% translate "Hello" %} {% trans "World" %}
```

And, `name` field and `person` model are translated in `my_app1/models.py` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name=_("first name") # Here
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name=_("last name") # Here
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('person') # Here
        verbose_name_plural = _('persons') # Here
```

And, this is `my_app1/admin.py` below:

```py
# "my_app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

And, `my_app1` is translated in `my_app1/apps.py` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/apps.py"

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyApp1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app1'
    verbose_name = _('my_app1') # Here
```

Now, run the command below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937133/unable-to-find-a-locale-path-to-store-translations-for-file-init-py#answer-76261223) explaining the command below:

```
django-admin makemessages -l fr
```

Then, `django.po` is created in `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-views.py
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-models.py
 |  |_admin.py
 |  └-apps.py
 |-my_app2
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html  
 └-locale
    └-fr
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          └-django.po # Here
```

Then, add `Bonjour`, `Monde`, `Anglais` and `Français` to each `msgstr ""` respectively in `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` as shown below:

```
# "locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"

...

#: .\core\settings.py:140
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais" # Here

#: .\core\settings.py:141
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français" # Here

#: .\my_app1\apps.py:7
msgid "my_app1"
msgstr "mon_app1" # Here

#: .\my_app1\models.py:6
msgid "first name"
msgstr "prénom"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:7
msgid "last name"
msgstr "nom de famille"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:13
msgid "person"
msgstr "personne"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:14
msgid "persons"
msgstr "personnes"

#: .\my_app1\views.py:5 .\templates\index.html:3
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "Bonjour" # Here

#: .\my_app1\views.py:5 .\templates\index.html:3
msgid "World"
msgstr "Monde" # Here

...
```

Then, run the command below to compile `django.po` to `django.mo`. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937133/unable-to-find-a-locale-path-to-store-translations-for-file-init-py#answer-76261223) explaining the command below:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

Then, `django.po` is compiled to `django.mo` in `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-views.py
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-models.py
 |  |_admin.py
 |  └-apps.py
 |-my_app2
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 └-locale
    └-fr
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.po
          └-django.mo # Here
```

Now, `http://localhost:8000/en/my_app1/` can show `Hello World` as shown below:

[image]

And, `Hello World` below is outputted on console:

```
Hello World
```

And, `http://localhost:8000/fr/my_app1/` can show `Bonjour Monde` as shown below:

[image]

And, `Bonjour Monde` below is outputted on console:

```
Bonjour Monde
```

And, `http://localhost:8000/en/admin/my_app1/person/add/` can show the English version of Django Admin including the app, model and field labels as shown below:

[image]

And, `http://localhost:8000/fr/admin/my_app1/person/add/` can show the French version of Django Admin including the app, model and field labels as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you set `English` as the 1st language in your browser as shown below. *This is [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/):

[image]

Now, if you access `http://localhost:8000/my_app1/`, then you are redirected to `http://localhost:8000/en/my_app1/` as shown below:

[image]

And, you set `French` as the 1st language in your browser as shown below.

[image]

Now, if you access `http://localhost:8000/my_app1/`, then you are redirected to `http://localhost:8000/fr/my_app1/` as shown below:

[image]

In addition again, you can remove `i18n_patterns()` from `admin` and `my_app1` paths in `core/urls.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
# from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_app1/', include('my_app1.urls'))
]

# urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
#     path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # Here
#     path('my_app1/', include('my_app1.urls')) # Here
# )
```

Then, you set `English` as the 1st language in your browser as shown below:

[image]

Now, `http://localhost:8000/my_app1/` can show `Hello World` as shown below:

[image]

And, you set `French` as the 1st language in your browser as shown below.

[image]

Now, `http://localhost:8000/my_app1/` can show `Bonjour Monde` as shown below:

[image]

Lastly, you can easily create **i18n switcher** following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460111/django-multilingual-and-switching-between-languages-on-template-side#answer-76565754) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76547342/how-to-create-i18n-switcher-for-django-admin#answer-76547343) explaining how to create **i18n switcher** for Django and Django Admin respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable the `LocaleMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) in your settings, to tell Django to do language detection based on the browser-settings. Changing your language preferences effectly sets the `Accept-Language` header. You might need to check in an incognito window, because other means of language detection have a higher priority, such as the user's session and the `django_language` cookie.

Comment: It'S actiavted. I've just updated the post. But thanks for the hint.