# django translation not working for me

Tags: python, django, translation, django-i18n

i cant force django to translate strings, choosen language from request is correct, but i have no translated strings.

maybe here could be problem: when i run shell, returned `language_code` is not equal as i have in `settings.py`

```
gettext = lambda s: s
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
   ('cs', gettext('Czech')),
   ('en', gettext('English')),
)

>>> from django.utils import translation
>>> 
>>> translation.get_language()
'en-us'
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
'en'
```

my message file is in `locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/django.{mo,po}`
i have this content there (translated abbr of week short names):

```
msgid "Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su"
msgstr "Po Út St Čt Pá So Ne"
```

in view, when i am getting right value 'cs'

```
print get_language() 
'cs'
```

and next line is `ugettext`

```
ugettext('Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su')
'Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su'
```

but i am expecting

```
'Po Út St Čt Pá So Ne'
```

can somebody tell me where could be problem? :o)

Comment: Django uses a session var to detect the user language, so probably that's the reason you are not getting the correct language in your shell.

Comment: Do you have activated the i18n middleware and configured the locale path? I was struggeling around some time ago at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/how-to-setup-up-django-translation-in-the-correct-way

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that translation is in `.po` file however is missing in `.mo` file. Try recompile messages by running

```
./manage.py compilemessages
```

Comment: Please put some notes about why it should fix the issue.

Comment: Expand your answer a little bit. Give us some proves, that this is really an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Make sure you have a correct-translated `.mo` file:

Execute `msgunfmt ./locale/jp/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo` to decompile `.mo` file:

Example output:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

msgid "world"
msgstr "日语世界"
```

### 2. Make sure Python's builtin `gettext` worked

Execute `python` under project root, enter the `Python shell`, then execute:

```py
import gettext
assert gettext.translation("django", "locale", ['jp']).gettext("world") == "日语世界"
```

### 3. Make sure `LOCALE_PATHS` is correctly set

Execute `python manage.py` under project root, enter the `Django shell`, then execute:

```py
from django.conf import settings
assert len(settings.LOCALE_PATHS) > 0
```

### 4. Make sure Django's `gettext` worked under corresponding language context

Enter `Django shell`, Execute:

```py
from django.utils import translation
with translation.override("jp"):
    assert translation.gettext("world") == "日语世界"
```

### 5. Make sure you have a standard language code, and django supports it

Enter `Django shell`, Execute:

```py
from django.utils import translation
assert 'ja' in translation.trans_real.get_languages()
assert 'zh-hans' in translation.trans_real.get_languages()
assert 'zh-hant' in translation.trans_real.get_languages()
assert 'zh-cn' not in translation.trans_real.get_languages()
```

### 6. Make sure you have the correct language context

**Server code**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.urls import path
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy, get_language


def home(_):
    return JsonResponse(dict(
        language=get_language(),
        hello=gettext_lazy("world")
    ), json_dumps_params=dict(ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home)
]
```

Test it:

`curl 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'Accept-Language: ja'`

Example response:

```json
{
    "language": "ja",
    "hello": "日语世界"
}
```

### The required config but not in default Django project:

1. `LOCALE_PATHS` The `locale` path is required for django to find `.mo` files
2. `MIDDLEWARE` The `LocaleMiddleware` is required for web project to detect context's language

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    BASE_DIR / "locale", # Here
)
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', # And here
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

### Another note:

Do **not** execute `mkdir locale` to create `locale` folder manually, `python manage.py makemessages` will create `locale` folder if your settings worked.

### The correct `i18n` steps for a new `Django` project:

1. Set `LOCALE_PATHS`
2. Set `LocaleMiddleware`
3. `python manage.py makemessages`
4. `python manage.py compilemessages`
5. `python manage.py runserver` to see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked the code whole night and found some clues. Mainly in trans_real.py and gettext.py. You can put a breakpoint in "translation" function.

1. The translation code are executed only once when app starts. So you need to reload the uwsgi to load the new version.
2. Po file is never used. gettext.py use "mo" file only.(in my laptop). So you have to compile messages after changing.
3. The "-" in the language code will be converted to "_" in locale path. For example "zh-CN" will be converted to "zh_CN". That's why the translation file cannot be found. I think it will be better if just using two characters as the language code. And the case sensitive should be considered in Linux system.

Comment: language to locale mapping is done with this function [to_locale](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c0a2388a1c4ead1afaec98e4ebc953a772ca3849/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L63), for example zh-hans will be zh_Hans.