# Unable to find a locale path to store translations for file __init__.py

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation, django-i18n

I'm trying to translate a Django app. I created some strings with `{% trans %}` in my templates. However, when I execute the following command in my app folder, I receive an error message:

```
$ django-admin.py makemessages -l fr 
CommandError: Unable to find a locale path to store translations for file __init__.py`
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Turns out you need to create a `locale` folder first using `mkdir locale`. If you are running the command from within an app folder, you need a `locale` folder within that app folder.

Comment: Thanks, helped me. Just execute the `makemessages` command from that `locale` directory if it's already available.

Comment: In Django 1.9 you need to define `LOCALE_PATHS` even if it is `locale` otherwise the compiled text won't be discoverable.

Comment: Note that this folder does *not* have any 's', and that it must be in the app folder (that way you don't have any `LOCALE_PATHS` to configure)

Comment: Here is more info on how Django discovers that directory - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations

Comment: You don't need to `cd` into an app dir to have per-app `locale` dirs. Just make sure all your apps with translation strings have a `locale` dir. Then `makemessages` [will find](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.3/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L533-L535) them. If you want a project-wide `locale` dir, simply create it in the project dir. These are the simplest solutions.

Comment: This makes no sense. The command says it scans all your code. I have "locale" folders in my apps, which it scans, but yet it still gives me this error...

Answer (score 36):

Actually you can configure where the locale folder is. In your settings.py add:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '/website/locale', )
```

Then create a folder for each of the languages you want to translate:

```
mkdir -p website/locale/de
```

Comment: you actually don't need to create a folder for each of the languages. django-admin makemessages will do this for you

Comment: This is confusing, are we supposed to create one entry for every app? Or store all locales for all apps in the same locale folder?

Comment: Since Django 4 this is `LOCALE_PATHS = [ BASE_DIR / 'my_app' / 'locale' ]`

Answer (score 20):

The problem is that the command is not run from the app directory but from the project directory. [This snippet from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages) explains it:

Turns out you need to create a `locale` folder first using `mkdir locale`.

> `./manage.py makemessages` […] Runs over the entire source tree **of the current directory** and pulls out all strings marked for translation. It creates (or updates) a message file in the conf/locale (in the Django tree) or locale (for project and application) directory.

So, you either run the command from the app directory:

```
$ cd app
$ django-admin makemessages -l <locale>
```

… or you define a project wide locale directory using `LOCALE_PATHS` and you can run `makemessages` from the main directory from there on.

Either way, you should check that the `./locale/`directory is present and create it using

```
$ mkdir locale
```

in case it's not.

Comment: You don't need to `cd` into an app dir to have per-app `locale` dirs. Just make sure all your apps with translation strings have a `locale` dir. Then `makemessages` [will find](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.3/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L533-L535) them.

Comment: And the default project-wide locale dir is `locale` (in the project dir). In any case, you don't need to `cd`, just make sure your locale dirs exist.

Comment: I have LOCALE_PATHS specified, and I still get this error when run from my project root.

Comment: @Cerin what about the folder? Did you create that as well?

Comment: @jnns Yes. The solution was I had to set PYTHONPATH to include my local project directory and also set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to point to my settings module. Othewise, django-admin couldn't import my settings module, even though it was in my CWD.

Answer (score 1):

If you want per-app `locale` dirs, simply create them in every app dir with [translation strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/#term-translation-string) (that has files with translation strings) before running `makemessages`. And `django` [will find](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.3/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L533-L535) them. No need to `cd`.

If you want one project-wide `locale` dir, create it in the project dir before running `makemessages`.

Answer (score 1):

You must create `locale` folder just under your `django-project` folder as shown below. *The folder name must be `locale` according to my experiments:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 └-locale # Here
```

Then, you can create `django.po` in each `locale/<...>/LC_MESSAGES/` with [the command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemessages-locale) below. *The command below can create or update one or more `django.po`:

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=en --locale=fr --locale=ja
```

Or:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en -l fr -l ja
```

Then, `django.po` is created in each `locale/<...>/LC_MESSAGES/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 └-locale
    |-en
    |  └-LC_MESSAGES
    |     └-django.po # Here
    |-fr
    |  └-LC_MESSAGES
    |     └-django.po # Here
    └-ja
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          └-django.po # Here
```

And, you can update all `django.po` in `locale` folder with [the command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemessages-all) below. *With the command below, you can only update `django.po` but cannot create `django.po`:

```
django-admin makemessages --all
```

Or:

```
django-admin makemessages -a
```

And, you can compile `django.po` to `django.mo` in each `locale/<...>/LC_MESSAGES/` with [the command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages) below:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

Then, `django.po` is compiled to `django.mo` in each `locale/<...>/LC_MESSAGES/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 └-locale
    |-en
    |  └-LC_MESSAGES
    |     |-django.po
    |     └-django.mo # Here
    |-fr
    |  └-LC_MESSAGES
    |     |-django.po
    |     └-django.mo # Here
    └-ja
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.po
          └-django.mo # Here
```

In addition, even if you create `locale` folder just under `core`, `app1` and `app2` folders as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-locale # Here
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  |-admin.py
 |  └-locale # Here
 └-app2
    |-models.py
    |-admin.py
    └-locale # Here
```

Then, run the command below:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en -l fr -l ja
```

Then, you will still get the error below according to my experiments and opposed to [How Django discovers translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) so you must create `locale` folder just under your `django-project` folder:

> CommandError: Unable to find a locale path to store translations for
> file manage.py. Make sure the 'locale' directory exists in an app or
> LOCALE_PATHS setting is set.

Comment: Thanks, after 4h of research, you are absolutely right. Presence of "locale" folder in the apps or in the main dir makes everything. LOCALE_PATHS is just needed for django to find the .mo file

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had `LOCALE_PATHS` set correctly, but I did not have the environment variables set. When I set the environment variables, I ran `python manage.py makemessages -l de` and it ran correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, one thing I noticed. I had to create the locale directory from Terminal within the app folder by issuing the command **mkdir locale**. While creating it from inside PyCharm I kept getting the error message:

**CommandError**: Unable to find a locale path to store translations for file allauth_introducao/**init**.py. Make sure the 'locale' directory exists in an app or LOCALE_PATHS setting is set.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same issue even though I have added LOCALE_PATHS to my project settings:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '/website/locale', )
```

I solved this issue by using the following method:

```
cd website
django-admin makemessages -l ar
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [jnns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41589737/1519716) from over 7 years ago.