# Django-jinja jinja2 templates i18n not translating

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, internationalization, jinja2

I have a problem with my Django Project, I use Jinja2 as template engine; specifically using django-jinja "providing unobtrusive Jinja2 support" :(.
My problem is that the strings in the template are not translated. Django recognizes the correct language, which can also be set by using the /i18n/setlang view.

What's weird is that the strings defined in Python ARE translated:

```
# in settings/base.py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

I have a `django.po` located in `locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` with a corresponding `django.mo`:

```
#: PyLatein/settings/base.py:144
msgid "English"
msgstr "Englisch"

#: PyLatein/settings/base.py:145
msgid "German"
msgstr "Deutsch"

#: templates/about.jinja:9
msgid "About"
msgstr "Über"
```

In my rendered template, the correct language is used (`LANGUAGE_CODE` is correct) and

```
if the language is en, then I can choose between "English" and "German",
if the language is de, then I can choose between "Englisch" and "Deutsch"!
```

-> so those are translated correctly, but `About` is still `About` and not `Über`, although in the template `about.jinja` I used

```
<h1 class="page-header">{{ _('About') }}</h1>
```

My middlewares are:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
)
```

And my template definition is:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        "DIRS": [osp.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "match_extension": ".jinja",
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
            ],
            "extensions": [
                "jinja2.ext.do",
                "jinja2.ext.loopcontrols",
                "jinja2.ext.with_",
                "jinja2.ext.i18n",
                "jinja2.ext.autoescape",
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.CsrfExtension",
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.CacheExtension",
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.TimezoneExtension",
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.UrlsExtension",
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.StaticFilesExtension",
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.DjangoFiltersExtension",
            ],
            "constants": {
                "settings": settings,
            },
            "translation_engine": "django.utils.translation",
        }
    },
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I use Python 3, Django 1.9.8 and django-jinja 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to specify the `LOCALE_PATHS`:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    osp.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)
```

I somehow assumed, that they were set to "locale" by default (because I read this in [Unable to find a locale path to store translations for file __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937133/django-commanderror-unable-to-find-a-locale-path-to-store-translations-for-fi)).

So that's why it didn't translate my strings. The words "English" and "German" were still translated, because django has a fallback locale in `$PYTHONPATH/django/conf/locale/<language>/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)`