# How to get Default language of browser in Django?

Tags: python, django, browser, default, http-accept-language

I want to fetch default language of browser. I have tried some code for this but nothing works for me correctly .

I can get an array of all languages that are activated in browser from this `request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`. But how I can get that language which is set as default.

Answer (score 9):

add the middleware `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` in `setting.py` following the middleware order as

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # other middleware ...
)
```

and use `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` to get the browser language.
source [http://www.janosgyerik.com/](http://www.janosgyerik.com/detect-language-preference-in-django-and-confirm-it-works/)

I used it to solve that problem in a project

Answer (score 2):

You can access current language through request.LANGUAGE_CODE as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-i18n

Comment: I think  `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`  gives you the value of language from  settings not browser .

Comment: if you use `django.template.context_processors.i18n` `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` is determined by browsers `Accept-Language` header as described here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/)

Comment: request.LANGUAGE_CODE is the activated language within Django. It's not necessarily equal to the browser's default HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE.

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.10 just change about this:

> ?: (1_10.W001) The MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting is deprecated in Django
>   1.10 and the MIDDLEWARE setting takes precedence. Since you've set MIDDLEWARE, the value of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is ignored.

Now do this instead:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    .......
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the 1st browser language which the code below gets is used to display the browser UI(Default) but not 100%. *I experimented with [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/), [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/), [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/) and [Opera](https://www.opera.com/).

```py
                                     # The 1st language
                                     # ↓↓ 
request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] # en,fr;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
```

For example, if you set `English`(1st) which is *This language is used to display the Google Chrome UI*(Default), `French`(2nd) and `Japanese`(3rd) on Google Chrome as shown below:

[image]

Then, the code below returns these languages in the order as above:

```py
                                     # The 1st language
                                     # ↓↓ 
request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] # en,fr;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
```

Next, if you set `French`(1st), `English`(2nd) which is *This language is used to display the Google Chrome UI*(Default) and `Japanese`(3rd) on Google Chrome as shown below:

[image]

Then, the code below returns these languages in the order as above:

```py
                                     # The 1st language
                                     # ↓↓ 
request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] # fr,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
```

In addition, if you want to automatically detect and apply the 1st browser language to your django website, set [LocaleMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.locale) to [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#middleware) between [SessionMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/middleware/#module-django.contrib.sessions.middleware) and [CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common) as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation#76475418) explaining it in details:

```py
# "settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware", # Here
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

And, you can get browser languages on frontend in JavaScript as shown below:

```html
<script>
console.log(navigator.languages); // ["fr", "en", "ja"]
console.log(navigator.language); // fr
</script>
```