# Django - custom translation (.mo file) strings doesn't work

Tags: python, django, localization

I tried to set up translation for Django. Built-in Django strings are correctly translated (e.g., in `/admin/`), so language selection works, but I can't get it to use the custom compiled .mo file.

I went step by step according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20893799/1023519), and some others, but without success - it looks like I have everything like in that one.

To points out things I checked up:

- LOCALE_PATHS is a tuple. I even tried to add multiple paths, but it didn't helped.
- `LocaleMiddleware` is before `CommonMiddleware` and after `SessionMiddleware`

settings.py:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'locale'),
)
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('cz', _('Czech')),
)
...

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'thermostat.middleware.thermostatMiddleware.ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

...
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'cz'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
...
```

(The `ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware` only removes `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header from `request.META`.)

In code, I'm using ugettext_lazy, and the .po file is generated as expected with `django-admin makemessages -a`. I translate it, run `django-admin  compilemessages`, which prints `processing file django.po in /[path to project]/locale/cz/LC_MESSAGES` - the path is correct, the .po file really exists there.

For example, I marked a model for translation like this:

```
class Probe(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Probe')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Probes')
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=200)
```

And this is where I ends - no matter what I tried, Django translates only is built-in messages and ignores custom strings. So in administration, I have translated all the buttons, but not the field and model names. Any ideas what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so as I was just about to send the question, I found the answer.

I was using `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'cz'`, and Django took it as an alias to `'cs'` (this is ok), but for some reason, it didn't load the custom .mo file. When I changed the language code to `cs` as it is in `django/conf/locale/` path, it began to work.

I do not understand why this happens, but at least it works.