# internationalization in django

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I want to internationalize my django app. After playing around according to the documentation and following this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/how-to-setup-up-django-translation-in-the-correct-way) I realized I don't need most of these options.

In my settings file I only use this:

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

So I got rid off  `LANGUAGE_CODE` and also didn't define any `LANGUAGES`.

Then I only added this to my views

```
from django.utils import translation
```

created language translations with `django-admin.py makemessages -l fr`

and  `django-admin.py compilemessages` and translated the messages in the `.po` file.

Now when I set the browser preference (Chrome) to French, all the text within `{% trans my text %}` in the html shows up translated. I guess it's explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/topics/i18n/#term-translation-string) on a higher level, I am just a little confused that it is that simple. Or is this just a hack that I am using?