# Translate django model choices

Tags: python, django, translation

i'm looking for a way to tranlate my models choices.
There is my model:

```
class CompteFinancier(models.Model):
      STATUS__OUI_NON = (
         ('--------', '--------'),
         (STATUS_OUI, 'Cas num 1'),
         (STATUS_NON, 'Cas num 2')
      )

       Cabinet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)
       requis_pour_deposer = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)
       credibilite_cabinet= models.CharField(choices=STATUS__OUI_NON)
```

**Can someone show me show to trans my choices cas please ?**

Answer (score 1):

This is how you specify the text that needs translation in your model

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class CompteFinancier(models.Model):

    STATUS__OUI_NON = (
         ('--------', '--------'),
         (STATUS_OUI, _('Cas num 1')),
         (STATUS_NON, _('Cas num 2'))
     )

     cabinet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)
     requis_pour_deposer = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)
     credibilite_cabinet = models.CharField(choices=STATUS__OUI_NON)
```

The full documentation for django translations can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#model-methods-short-description-attribute-values). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20893799/1233289) for a step by step guide for setting up internationalization in django

Comment: Thank you for everything, I found the solution thanks to your indications.

Comment: How can I add translation to the label "STATUS__OUI_NON "?