# How to make the urls with and without a language prefix work in Django i18n?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-i18n

This is my `django-project` as shown below. *I'm learning [Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/) with **Django 4.2.1**:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  |-admin.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-app2
 └-locale
    └-en
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.mo
          └-django.po
```

And, this is `core/settings.py` which sets `fr` to [LANGUAGE_CODE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#language-code) as a default language code as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # ...
]

# ...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr' # Here

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', _('Français')),
    ('en', _('Anglais')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
   BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]
```

And, this is `app1/views.py` which returns the default french word `Bonjour` from `test` view as shown below:

```py
# "app1/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def test(request):        # Here
    return HttpResponse(_("Bonjour"))
```

And, this is `app1/urls.py` with the path set `test` view in `urlpatterns` as shown below:

```py
# "app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "app1"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.test, name="test") # Here
]
```

And, this is `core/urls.py` with [i18n_patterns()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) set `admin` and `app1` paths in `urlpatterns` as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls'))
)
```

Then, `http://localhost:8000/fr/app1/` can show `Bonjour` as shown below:

[image]

And, `http://localhost:8000/en/app1/` can show `Hello` as shown below:

[image]

Now, I also want to show `Bonjour` with `http://localhost:8000/app1/` but it redirects to `http://localhost:8000/en/app1/` showing `Hello` as shown below:

[image]

Actually, if I set [prefix_default_language=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) to `i18n_patterns()` in `core/urls.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False # Here
)
```

Then, `http://localhost:8000/app1/` can show `Bonjour` as shown below:

[image]

But, `http://localhost:8000/fr/app1/` doesn't work to show `Bonjour` as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I show `Bonjour` with both `http://localhost:8000/fr/app1/` and `http://localhost:8000/app1/`?

Answer (score 0):

In `core/urls.py`, you should add `fr/` to `admin` and `app1` paths in `urlpatterns`, then add [i18n_patterns()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) set `admin` and `app1` paths and [prefix_default_language=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) to `urlpatterns` as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
          ↓↓↓ Here
    path('fr/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('fr/app1/', include('app1.urls')),
]         ↑↑↑ Here 

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns( # Here
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

Then, `http://localhost:8000/fr/app1/` can show `Bonjour` as shown below:

[image]

Also, `http://localhost:8000/app1/` can show `Bonjour` as shown below:

[image]

And, `http://localhost:8000/en/app1/` can show `Hello` as shown below:

[image]